# Get Texture from google play game services Icon Uri in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, google-play-games

I am trying to show user profile icon in my game in libgdx. In the android side of code, i can get the image uri for the player using `mParticipants.get(i).getIconImageUri()` which gives me the Uri. But I can't find a way to convert the Uri to Texture which i can consume in my libgdx code.

I tried first getting the bitmap from Uri using the code

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = application.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this gives me a security error.

Other answers on google shows me the ways, all of which include the ways to show image in an Android ImageView but i need a texture which i can use in my libgdx game to show the image

I have also tried adding following permission to my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Even then i am still getting security error. Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: security exception may be due to you're using targetSDK >=23, that required runtime permission for Dangerous Permissions.

Comment: Bitmap ?? How you use in core module, May be you can get String from android by interfacing to core module then get Texture data from link address, after then keep data in local fileHandler and fetch that data from local file and populate in your project.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan bitmap can be converted to libgdx texture easily which can then be used in core module as ** new Texture(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888) ** 
the methods used to get the http url are deprecated

Comment: what do you think by this `new Texture(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)`, you're converting `Bitmap` to `Texture`. I don't think so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research it seemed to me that it is **Not Possible** to get the bitmap by reading the input stream for the Uri. The only way to do this is using the `ImageManager`

The sample code for achieving this is:

```
private void SetUserIconForPlayer(final Player player, Uri uri)
{
    ImageManager mgr = ImageManager.create(application);
    mgr.loadImage(new ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoaded(Uri uri,final Drawable drawable, boolean isRequestedDrawable) {
            if(isRequestedDrawable)
            {
                Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        player.SetUserIcon(GetTextureFromDrawable(drawable));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }, uri);
}
```